Xcode 15 Sudden Warning - This code path does interprocess communication underneath
Recently I made the switch to Xcode 15 and I'm receiving a runtime warning concerning an object I've created that listens to updates from the volume (such as when the user updates the volume using the phone's controls and not the media player within the app). I haven't changed this line of code for over a year and at no point in Xcode 14 was this message thrown.
final class VolumeObserver: ObservableObject {

@Published var volume: Float = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume //line the warning comes from

// Audio session object
private let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

// Observer
private var progressObserver: NSKeyValueObservation!

func subscribe() {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
        try session.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("cannot activate session")
    }
    
    progressObserver = session.observe(\.outputVolume) { [self] (session, value) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.volume = session.outputVolume
        }
    }
}

func unsubscribe() {
    self.progressObserver.invalidate()
}

init() {
    subscribe()
}

}
to which I use a onReceive function in the view to update the value of the volume
            .onReceive(self.volObs.$volume) { value in
            if self.isMuted {
                self.isMuted = false
            }
            self.volumeLevel = value
        }

I've read there was an Xcode 14 bug where this message would occur when it shouldn't so I'm not sure why it's now all of a sudden showing up.
